# Restrict my code to write to a specific folder C#

Tags: c#

I got a folder in C called "donotcopy". I want to protect it and no matter what not to be allowed to create files within.

My intuitive solution was just to create a str with same name and where user enters a destination it just checks if it's the same.

Example:

```
class FileCreation
{
    public static void Main()
    {
        string notallowed = ("c:\\donotcopy");
        string filename = ("Nick.txt");

        Console.WriteLine("Enter the full path to create an empty file.");
        string path = Console.ReadLine();
        path = path.ToLower();

        while (notallowed == path)
        {
            Console.WriteLine("The chosen path is not allowed please try another one.");
            path = Console.ReadLine();
            path = path.ToLower();
        }
        using (FileStream fs = File.Create(path + filename)) ;
    }
}
```

The problem is if the user enters the destination as "c:.\donotcopy" it will still create the file inside the restricted folder.

Comment: Split the path and check hierarchy

Comment: Set appropriate permissions on the folder.

Comment: `if (Path.GetRelativePath(notallowed, path) ... something)` https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.io.path.getrelativepath?view=net-6.0

Comment: If you do not want users to write to a folder, controlling it coding into the application is a bad idea. Users could write to it using other methods (like windows file explorer)

Comment: "no matter what" - then setting permissions is the only options. Otherwise, there are ways to circumvent your check for a specific path. e.g. [symbolic links](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows-server/administration/windows-commands/mklink) will make the same directory accessible by anotjher name.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can make use of the `DirectoryInfo` class, which will allow you to retrieve info about the full path of a directory.

```
class FileCreation
{
   public static void Main()
   {
      string notallowed = ("c:\\donotcopy");
      string filename = ("Nick.txt");

      Console.WriteLine("Enter the full path to create an empty file.");
      DirectoryInfo directory = new DirectoryInfo(Console.ReadLine());

      while (notallowed.Equals(directory.FullName, StringComparison.InvariantCultureIgnoreCase))
      {
         Console.WriteLine("The chosen path is not allowed please try another one.");
         directory = new DirectoryInfo(Console.ReadLine());
      }

      string fullPath = Path.Combine(directory.FullName, filename);
      using (FileStream fs = File.Create(fullPath)) ;
   }
}
```

Comment: You may want to edit it and add why OP's coding is not wise, check the question comments for more info.